# How to change index to value in an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```js
const arr = [{
  "name": "Toyota"
}, {
  "name": "Renault"
}, {
  "name": "Jeep"
}]

const array_unique = (arr) => Array.from(new Set(arr));

const car = array_unique(
  arr.map((item) => item.name),
).sort();
console.log(car); // => ['Toyota', 'Renault', 'Jeep']

const car_map = Object.fromEntries(
  car.map((car, index) => [car, index]),
);
console.log(car_map); // => {Toyota: 0, Renault: 1, Jeep: 2,}
```

Is there any possibility to change the index like 0, 1, 2 into car name
like:

```
{Toyota: Toyota, Renault: Renault, Jeep: Jeep,}
```

Comment: You can but why would you want to? You're just duplicating data when it's not necessary. Note that object string values would need to be quoted.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have to use that car map later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map()` and `Object.fromEntries()` methods

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "Toyota" },
  { name: "Renault" },
  { name: "Jeep" },
];

const array_unique = (arr) => Array.from(new Set(arr));

const carNames = array_unique(arr.map((item) => item.name)).sort();

const carMap = Object.fromEntries(carNames.map((name) => [name, name]));

console.log(carMap);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to over-complicate it. [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over the array and for each object return a new object when the key has been replaced by a [computed property name](https://eloquentcode.com/computed-property-names-in-javascript) that uses the value of the object's `name` property.

```js
const arr=[{name:"Toyota"},{name:"Renault"},{name:"Jeep"}];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  return { ...acc, [obj.name]: obj.name };
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Additional documentation

- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)